# Javascript object in object error

Tags: javascript, object, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a weird bug in internet explorer 7 and 8 when I am using javascript object. It work in IE9 and all the others.

When I am using an object and any of my parameter in the object is "class" internet explorer 7 and 8 stop doing anything.

I am using jquery 1.8.2.

I'll show you some code.

```
var obj = {
             data:{class:'image',action:'getAllFkId',type:nbType, fkid:id},
             success:function(json){
                alert('hi');

            }
        };
        this.ajax(obj);
```

Code of "this.ajax" (the "this" is an object) :

```
ajax : function(params){ 

        var defaults = {
            url: '../index.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(){/*Function handler*/}
        }
        var options = $.extend(defaults, params);

        $.ajax(options);
        return this;
    }, // ..... rest of code
```

If I change the name of the parameter to anything else it works.

```
// This is just fine foo instead of class
var obj = {
         data:{foo:'image',action:'getAllFkId',type:nbType, fkid:id},
         success:function(json){
            alert('hi');

        }
    };
    this.ajax(obj);
```

I would like to understand why IE7-8 won't work with "class" as a parameter.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of some older browsers, you'll need to wrap `class` in quotation marks.

```
data:{"class":"image",...
```

While ECMAScript allows reserved words as property identifiers, some older browsers didn't allow it.

Comment: Thanks you very much for this answer. I didn't know that `class` was an property for older browser.